# Hyperledger fabric: One peer in two organizations possibility

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, peer

In Hyperledger fabric, can one peer be part of two organizations? Please add as much possible reasoning in the support of your answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Identity of a peer is mapped with the organisation that owns it and Peers are provided with identical certificates for verification.So,one peer can be associated with single organisation.

More details in their official doc : [here](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/peers/peers.html#peers-and-identity)

> The mapping of identity to organization is provided by a component
>   called a Membership Service Provider (MSP) — it determines how a peer
>   gets assigned to a specific role in a particular organization and
>   accordingly gains appropriate access to blockchain resources.
>   Moreover, a peer can be owned only by a single organization, and is
>   therefore associated with a single MSP.

Comment: seems reasonable